# Convert value of a bonus year column based on product and date of another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-arithmetic

```
performance period        product          saledate
------------------------------------------------------
2019-01                    xyz             01/01/2019
2019-01                    xyz             02/02/2019
2020-01                    xyz             01/01/2020
2020-01                    xyz             02/02/2020
```

Bonus based on months in which sale of product occurred. Annual bonus system now changed to bi-annual periods so all these sales should have a performance period of 2019-01 for the xyz product.

I have 1m+ rows like this with various products for which the performance period needs to be changed

I want the dates to return with a same performance period (2019-01)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and change the schema to store the performance period using the first day of the period, in an actual datetime column. Same for the sales date: it looks like you have a varchar column, which is _very bad_. FIXING this (because the schema really is **broken** right now) will improve performance for this query, without exaggeration, by multiple orders of magnitude

Answer (score 0):

You can use a math trick to get the result you want.

If the year is odd number, just truncate the sale date to the year, in SQL server, it can be done by `dateadd(year, datediff(year,0, SALEDATE), 0)`.

If the year is even number, first substract one year out of the sale date, and then truncate the sale dat to the year using the similiar `dateadd(year, datediff(year,0, LAST_YEAR_SALEDATE), 0)` code.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d955a/8):

```
select
   case when year(saledate) % 2 = 1 then dateadd(year, datediff(year,0, saledate), 0)
        else dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0,DATEADD(year,-1,saledate)), 0)
   end as "performance period",
   product,
   saledate
from
    sales
```

| performance period | product | saledate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z | xyz | 2019-01-01 |
| 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z | xyz | 2019-02-02 |
| 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z | xyz | 2020-01-01 |
| 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z | xyz | 2020-02-02 |

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you just need to truncate the sale year to the closest uneven year. Typically, all sales of years 2019 and 2020 belong to the *2019* performance period.

We can use date arithmetics like so:

```
select t.*, 
    year(saledate) + year(saledate) % 2 - 1 as performance_year
from mytable t
```

This adjusts the year using operation `... % 2`, which returns `0` when its left operand is an even value, and `1` if it's uneven.

I am unsure why you want *fixed* string `'-01'` prefixed to the performance year - but we can concatenate it if needed:

```
select t.*, 
    concat(year(saledate) + year(saledate) % 2 - 1, '-01') as performance_period
from mytable t
```

If you wanted to actually `update` your data (backup your +1M rows first!):

```
update mytable
set performance_period = concat(year(saledate) + year(saledate) % 2 - 1, '-01')
```